# CentOS 6.4 shows only logo

Tags: linux, centos, boot, centos6

I've had centOS 6.4 server for some time and everything was working fine.
Now after the installation of postgres DB it won't boot. The DB was working fine and it shut down normally.

It shows centos logo with progress circle. The progress circle fills and nothing happens.

How can I start to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing Alt+D to switch from "graphical boot" to a more informative textual one, so you can see at what stage the boot is stuck.